# Heisenberg uncertainty principle applied to large bodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose I have a ball of a certain radius inside a box (with the length bigger than the radius) such that the ball fits in the box. The ball has a large mass (1 Kg). Heisenberg uncertainty principle tells me that I cannot say for sure if the ball is moving or is at rest. If I'm interested in the probability that the ball is at some place, I suppose that this probability is uniform inside the box, since the ball has a large mass. But how about the speed probability? Is it uniform too? I think yes, but I'm not 100% sure beaucase I cannot write a proof.

Comment: The problem that you have is that you can't treat the large body as a point mass, i.e. any attempt to measure its position with that kind of precision would be measuring internal degrees of freedom, instead (e.g. molecular vibrations).

Comment: But I can measure the center of the ball for instance. Suppose the ball can only move to one direction in the box, and no translation is allowed, so the ball has 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: While the theory suggests that you can, you can't do it in reality. In reality you would start seeing thermal excitations long before you ever reach the necessary precision to measure the quantum effect. At that point it becomes a non-question for you and for nature. It simply doesn't matter. That's not the case for all quantum effects. Many of them do survive the scaling of the system towards macroscopic size. Magnetism is an example of that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [the Heisenberg uncertainty principle:](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html)

[image: HUP]

Here is h_bar 1.054571726(47)×10^−34 joulesecond

All it needs is some algebra to see that a kilogram ball moving at a micron per second and measurement accuracies of the order of a micron will still fulfill the HUP constraint as h_bar is a very small number. For classical dimensions h_bar is essentially zero and the HUP always holds.

When one goes to dimensions of less than nanometers and masses of the order of molecules then one is in the quantum mechanical regime and can start talking of uncertainties .

Comment: Ok. I understood that. But as small as $\hbar$ is I cannot say with certainty if the ball is moving or is at rest, am I right?

Comment: ". But as small as ℏ is I cannot say with certainty if the ball is moving or is at rest, am I right? " -- That depends on the state of the ball.

Comment: Yes, except the uncertainty is so tiny that it has no meaning in the everyday and down to microns context.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be applied to a large body in our classical universe. The larger the body is, the less kinetic energy it has and therefore very negligible wave function. So, we are more certain that it is at a particular position.